# Elixir Phoenix RabbitMQ MatchError

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am creating messaging app where app A need to send message to app B using rabbitMQ. I am developing using Phoenix and on rabbitMQ web site I found tutorial how to implement rabbitmq with elixir but I don't know how to use it in my Phoenix app. I tried to add code, which I find on rabbit tutorial web site, to my Phoenix page_controller.ex

```
  defmodule ApplicationA.PageController do
  use ApplicationA.Web, :controller
  use AMQP

  def index(conn, _params) do
    {:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open
    {:ok, channel} = AMQP.Channel.open(connection)

    AMQP.Queue.declare(channel, "hello")

    AMQP.Basic.publish(channel, "", "hello", "Hello World!")
    IO.puts " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'"

    AMQP.Connection.close(connection)

    render conn, "index.html"
  end
end
```

but I get this error

```
no match of right hand side value: {:error, :econnrefused}
```

in line 6

```
{:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open
```

Con somebody help me how I should do this on the good way?

Comment: Is RabbitMQ running on localhost port 5672?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify connection settings for RabbitMQ.

Add in your `config/dev.exs` something like:

```
config :my_app, :rabbitmq,
  host: "${RABBITMQ_HOSTNAME}", 
  port: 5672, 
  username: "${RABBITMQ_UID}", 
  password: "${RABBITMQ_PWD}"
```

and then load them:

```
rabbit_settings = Application.get_env :my_app, :rabbitmq
{:ok, connection} = AMQP.Connection.open(rabbit_settings)
```